# Primefaces: multiple datatables on page - sorting

Tags: sorting, jsf-2, primefaces, datatable

I'm using Primefaces 5.2.

On my page, I have several p:datatables with the same columns and the same sortBy expression.

Something like:

```
<p:dataTable .. id="tab1">
   <p:column sortBy="#{prop1}">
      #{prop1}
   </p:column>
</p:dataTable>


<p:dataTable .. id="tab2">
   <p:column sortBy="#{prop1}">
      #{prop1}
   </p:column>
</p:dataTable>
```

Sorting works fine so far, but I get strange behaviour and finally a NullPointerException if I sort one of the tables (let's call it table A) and then refresh the page (e.g. by firing a h:commandButton). In this case ALL tables have the same column highlighted as table A. Also, as soon as I sort a table other than table A afterwards, the following exception occurs:

> 21:33:36,149 SEVERE javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.application (default task-25) Error Rendering View[/stocks.xhtml]: java.lang.NullPointerException
>       at org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTable.findColumnInGroup(DataTable.java:905) [primefaces-5.2.jar:5.2]
>       at org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTable.findColumn(DataTable.java:896) [primefaces-5.2.jar:5.2]
>       at org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTable.getSortColumn(DataTable.java:1401) [primefaces-5.2.jar:5.2]
>       at org.primefaces.component.datatable.feature.SortFeature.singleSort(SortFeature.java:136) [primefaces-5.2.jar:5.2]
>       at org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTableRenderer.preRender(DataTableRenderer.java:109) [primefaces-5.2.jar:5.2]
>       at org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTableRenderer.encodeEnd(DataTableRenderer.java:83) [primefaces-5.2.jar:5.2]
>       at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:919) [jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.8.jar:2.2.8]
>       at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1863) [jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.8.jar:2.2.8]
>       at com.sun.faces.facelets.component.RepeatRenderer.encodeChildren(RepeatRenderer.java:104) [jsf-impl-2.2.8-jbossorg-1.jar:]
>       at com.sun.faces.facelets.component.UIRepeat.process(UIRepeat.java:621) [jsf-impl-2.2.8-jbossorg-1.jar:]
>       at com.sun.faces.facelets.component.UIRepeat.encodeChildren(UIRepeat.java:1110) [jsf-impl-2.2.8-jbossorg-1.jar:]
>       at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1856) [jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.8.jar:2.2.8]
>       at javax.faces.render.Renderer.encodeChildren(Renderer.java:176) [jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.8.jar:2.2.8]
>       at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:889) [jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.8.jar:2.2.8]
>       at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1856) [jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.8.jar:2.2.8]
>       at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1859) [jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.8.jar:2.2.8]
>       at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1859) [jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.8.jar:2.2.8]
>       at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:456) [jsf-impl-2.2.8-jbossorg-1.jar:

Comment: Is that an ajax or non-ajax refresh? Also normally I guess you would have for example var="item" and sortBy="#{item.prop1}"

Comment: It's a non-ajax refresh. Yes, I have it like var="item" and sortBy="#{item.prop1}". Above is just an abbreviation.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to add rowStatePreserved="true" to the table containing the other tables. This was added in Primefaces 5.1.14 and is part of JSF 2.1.

Credits for: sdjavaudvk (http://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=43441).

```
<p:dataTable id="tab1" var="resumo" value="#{resumoView.resumos}" rows="20" 
                         paginator="true" 
                         rowsPerPageTemplate="5,10,15,20" 
                         rowStatePreserved="true">
...
```

Comment: This is indeed a little known 'trick' to solve some problems IF the datatables are in an iterator. PrimeFaces 5.3.something and 6.0 have some additional things implemented to prevent issues in itereators

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using a different form for each datatable? Like this:

```html
<h:form>
  <p:dataTable id="tab1"> ... </p:dataTable>
</h:form>
  
<h:form>
  <p:dataTable id="tab2"> ... </p:dataTable>
</h:form>
```

Answer (score 0):

We encountered the same problem on Primefaces6.0.

We had a form containing two tables, and a specific column can be either filtered via a list of values (filterMatchMode exact) or via an input text (filterMatchMode contains).
The first table didn't have a working filter (we encountered the same NullPointerException as you did), and the second was working fine.

The two tables were in a component, and the column filtered and sorted in the two tables was built conditionnaly with the JSTL like this :

```html
    <c:choose>
        <c:when test="#{cc.attrs.filterOperatorExact}">
            <p:column headerText="Header name"
                sortBy="#{vector.operatorForDisplay}"
                filterBy="#{vector.operatorForDisplay}" filterMatchMode="exact"
                filterOptions="#{cc.attrs.filtersOperatorList}">
                <h:outputText value="#{vector.operatorForDisplay}" />
            </p:column>
        </c:when>
        <c:otherwise>
            <p:column headerText="Header name"
                sortBy="#{vector.operatorForDisplay}"
                filterBy="#{vector.operatorForDisplay}" filterMatchMode="contains">
                <h:outputText value="#{vector.operatorForDisplay}" />
            </p:column>
        </c:otherwise>
    </c:choose>
```

Using the "JSF way" to do this with the rendered attribute, the problem disappeared :

```html
    <p:column headerText="Header name"
        sortBy="#{vector.operatorForDisplay}"
        filterBy="#{vector.operatorForDisplay}" filterMatchMode="exact"
        filterOptions="#{cc.attrs.filtersOperatorList}"
        rendered="#{cc.attrs.filterOperatorExact}">
        <h:outputText value="#{vector.operatorForDisplay}"/>
    </p:column>
    <p:column headerText="Header name"
        sortBy="#{vector.operatorForDisplay}"
        filterBy="#{vector.operatorForDisplay}" filterMatchMode="contains"
        rendered="#{not cc.attrs.filterOperatorExact}">
        <h:outputText value="#{vector.operatorForDisplay}"/>
    </p:column>
```

Hope it helps.